# Qt 5.3.2 QtQuick QML application doesn't play youtube video

Tags: macos, youtube, webkit, qml, qtquick2

I have basic WebView item and Qt SDK 5.3.2. I've tried to browse several youtube videos. Actually, audio plays only. But video, doest not.

Only black screen visible:
[image]

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtWebKit 3.0
import QtWebKit.experimental 1.0

ScrollView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    WebView {
        id: webview
        anchors.fill: parent
        url: "https://www.youtube.com/"

        experimental.preferences.pluginsEnabled: true

        onNavigationRequested: {
            request.action = WebView.AcceptRequest;
        }
    }
}
```

After discovering some helps I've find out a way to test loaded page:

```
url: "http://www.youtube.com/html5"
```

This URL shows me following result:
[image]

What should I do to make available following features in my app:

- Media Source Extension MSE
- MSE & H.264
- MSE & Web VP9

Answer (score 2):

This might be issue with Qtwebkit, now QT is not supporting Qtwebkit so I think better to move to QTwebengine , here is an example for the webengine code. Web engine initialization part is as follows

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QtWebEngine::initialize();

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Qml part to load the web is

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtWebEngine 1.0

Window {
    width: 1024
    height: 750
    visible: true
    WebEngineView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        url: "http://www.qt.io"
    }
}
```

Please refer this link for more details
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-webengine-minimal-example.html

MSE will support from QT 5.5 version, Proprietary codecs can be enabled by passing the following option to qmake when building Qt WebEngine:

```
qmake WEBENGINE_CONFIG+=use_proprietary_codecs
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried same thing in Qt 5.4.0, and for me it won't play YouTube video at all (just displays error and suggests to reload page).

It seems that problem lays in `WebView` (WebKit) element.

What I did is:

- installed Qt 5.4.0 MSVC version
- imported QtWebEngine
- used `WebEngineView` element

And it worked.

**Keep in mind that WebKit will be deprecated in next Qt version and you will need to move to Chromium (QtWebEngine).**

---

References:

https://www.qtdeveloperdays.com/2013/sites/default/files/presentation_pdf/Webkit.pdf

http://www.qt.io/qt5-4/?utm_source=qtproject&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=qt54release#section-3